# Appium & Webdriver (webdriverjs) - cannot execute javascript code

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I am trying to execute javascript Appium test using [WD](https://github.com/admc/wd). My code should look something like this:

```
"use strict";

var wd = require("wd");
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
var jQuery = require("jQuery");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;
var desired = {
    "appium-version": "1.0",
    platformName: "iOS",
    platformVersion: "7.1",
    deviceName: "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)",
    app: "/Users/{myuser}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{MyApp}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
};

var browser = wd.promiseChainRemote("0.0.0.0", 4723);


browser.init(desired).then(function() {

    var getIframe = function(){
        //var r = jQuery('#myIframe');
        return {'response':"1"};//only for testing that this method works...
    };

    return browser

        .elementByName("Show Webview").click()
        .sleep(10000)
        .contexts().then(function (contexts) { // get list of available views. Returns array: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"]
            return browser.context(contexts[1]); // choose the webview context
        })
        .execute(getIframe).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        })
        .sleep(10000)
        .fin(function() {
            //return browser.quit();
        });
}, function(e){console.log(e);}).done();
```

I am running this code using `node mytest.js`.

The problem is that I cannot execute js code. In this case I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [execute()] Not JSON response
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comments:

1. What I finally am trying to do here is access and manipulate an iFrame in my code (in the same domain), using `iFrame.contentDocument`
2. My insperation for using 'execute like this is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888183/how-to-execute-custom-javascript-code-in-webdriverjs) post

tnx,
Yaniv

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to execute javascript using "safeExecute" method, instead of "execute".
My issue now is that I do not have access to "window" object, so I cannot run "jQuery" or "window.document.getElementById"...