# Can't execute java script using Android Driver

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I am using `appium 1.1.16` and `java-client-3.3.0.jar` for running test on android device. I am getting error when I am trying to execute `javascript`, any help would be appreciated.

> //1. Code: Initialising driver:

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
        logger.info("Added capability: deviceName = Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        logger.info("Added capability: platformName = Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("app", appFile.getAbsolutePath());
        logger.info("Added capability: app = "+appFile.getAbsolutePath());

        capabilities.setCapability("serial", deviceID);
        logger.info("Added capability: serial = "+deviceID);

        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "60");

        /** initializing appium driver */
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        //driver = new SwipableWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("Added Driver Timeout = "+timeout +" Sec. ");
```

> //2. Code: Executing Java script:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byLocator));

        WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(byLocator);
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webelement);
```

> Exception thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'VDO60.local', ip: '172.16.0.53', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Session ID: b00c752f-fe5f-4774-8041-593a1b64fa1e
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=/Users/navneetsharma/Desktop/qaAutomation/qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/tc_data/sdk/android/VdopiaSDKSample_StandAlone/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=Android, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=60, app=/Users/navneetsharma/Desktop/qaAutomation/qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/tc_data/sdk/android/VdopiaSDKSample_StandAlone/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk, platformName=Android, deviceName=Android, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5}, locationContextEnabled=false, newCommandTimeout=60, platformVersion=5.0, databaseEnabled=false, platformName=Android, deviceName=4d0025b440ca90d5, webStorageEnabled=false, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:556)
    at projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler.clickElement(ObjectsHandler.java:47)
    at projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler.menuNavigation(ObjectsHandler.java:195)
    at projects.sdk.lib.SDKPerformActions.performAction(SDKPerformActions.java:74)
    at projects.sdk.lib.GetResults.getDeviceJsonResult(GetResults.java:167)
    at projects.sdk.lib.GetResults.getResults(GetResults.java:76)
    at projects.sdk.SDKAdServingTest.sdkTest(SDKAdServingTest.java:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136336/appium-webdriver-webdriverjs-cannot-execute-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

As per the link - [Appium & Webdriver (webdriverjs) - cannot execute javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136336/appium-webdriver-webdriverjs-cannot-execute-javascript-code)

Can you try command: "safeExecute" method, instead of "execute".

Comment: I don't find any option safeExecute in AndroidDriver -- (appium)